# Are there any Type2-charged non-car vehicles?

Tags: electric-vehicles

To support my idea of *Sustainable Living*, I'd like to reuse costs spent by my family of purchasing high-end Type2 charger by using it not just to charge up our EV car.

Are there any battery-powered non-car vehicles (bikes, motorbikes, scooters, etc.) that can be charged (without any socket modifications) from a regular Type2 cable that my charger has?

Or is this socket solely for charging EVs only?

Comment: You'd need something with a big battery to justify a connector that large and complex. Even a large motorbike could fully charge in an hour or less from one. So there's no benefit rto having it, and on a bicycle the extra 1-2kg from the socket would be significant.

Comment: You can not save by buying more.

Comment: Do you mean like ordinary golf carts ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 I mean anything smaller than an EV, powered via Type 2.

Comment: Will Prowse suggested recently that he might be able to charge his very large "portable power station" things that way. Or at least faster than the 100V/15A that the US is normally limited to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, electric motorcycles (actual motorcycles rather than e-bikes or pedelecs) can charge from Type 2 (and CCS) chargers.

Examples include  [Energica](https://www.energicamotor.com/us/), [Harley Davidson Livewire](https://www.livewire.com/en-gb/) and [Zero motorcycles](https://www.zeromotorcycles.com/ride-electric/charging-and-range)

Comment: For Zero it [seems](https://www.zeromotorcycles.com/ride-electric/charging-and-range) that Type 2 is not supported. The Level 2 graphics shows something different to me than Type 2. It is weird, because Level 3 charging shows CSS and CSS is extension of Type 2. But... the graphic in Level 2 charging is surely different than a typical Type 2 socket.

Answer (score 1):

First, to be clear, the type 2 charger *isn't a charger at all*. It's [just a switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y) (the video disclaims Europe but actually Mennekes works the same way with same protocols, just with 3-phase sometimes available).  It goes "CLACK"! Well it also contains an RCD aka GFCI, and a simple signal generator to tell your car how much power is safe to draw from the wall.  The entire comm protocol can be explained in 20 minutes. If you [watched that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y), *it was*.

The charger is on the car. It's the size of a suitcase, water cooled, and it gets HOT.

### Anything that takes 230V can have a Type 2 port added.

If it already has a Type 1 (J1772) port, then change it to a Type 2 and wire it to the same pins.  You won't use the L2 or L3 pins.

I assume anything with a Type 1 port has been gray-market imported from North America.  The Type 2/Mennekes port is not used there.

Otherwise you can take its 230V (or 120V) wall plug, and reroute that to a [Type 2 inlet](https://eauto.si/metron-shop/product/type-2-mennekes-car-socket-inlet-panel/), pins L1 and N... with a couple of necessary steps.

[image]

First, you need to manage the signal on the CP line.  You normally have a 2740 ohm resistor across the CP and PE pins; when your device wants to charge, add a 1300 ohm resistor and the EVSE will go CLACK!

Second, if your battery charger can pull more than about 4 amps, you need to add a relay to disconnect it when the EVSE is offering less amps than the charger needs. That's a blunt instrument, but it's easy to implement with an Arduino.